# How would I open certain links from Mozilla Firefox in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I want to open certain links, like https://firebase.google.com/docs/ in chrome, since Firefox(my default browser) seems to have a [problem rendering these webpages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ76A.png). When I open it in Chrome, it properly renders it. How can I make Firefox open these links in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extension : [open in chrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome-browser/)

Comment: Or have them both open side by side and drag the URL from the Firefox address bar to the Chrome one. Or copy and paste.